# Java POJO to JSON conversion tool?

Tags: java, arrays, tostring, pojo

I have a `Java Object` that I am trying to map into a `JSON` object.

Is there an online tool where I can print the Java object using `toString()` and convert it to a `JSON` object?

I know that I can do it in code using e.g:

https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: I don't think there is any. Suggesting to use [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/json003.htm) instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you just need the JSON in plain text so you can copy/paste or something. If so, you could set up something incredibly simple using Spring Boot and Jackson, map whatever JSON you're trying to copy to a URI using `@RequestMapping("/")`, and as long as you have your controller annotated with `@RestController`, whatever object you return in the method will automatically be parsed to a JSON when Jackson is on your classpath. Then just go to localhost in your browser and the request uri you specified and you'll have a plain text JSON as a response. Something like this:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public SomeClass returnObjectInBrowser() {
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
        someClass.doStuff();

        return someClass;
    }
}
```

Comment: what could be the request uri typed in the browser for the example class Controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `toString()` method of the bean class to convert object to JSON string

```
@Override <br>
public String toString() {
    
        String str = "";
        // Converts object to json string using GSON
        // Gson gson = new Gson();
        // str = gson.toJson(this);
        
        //Converts object to json string using Jaxson
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
        try {
            str = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.error(exception);
        }
        return str;

}
```